# Providing the respondent with the file upload in the form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I continue to expand my project - the problem described at [Selecting a subfolder to upload based on the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73970317/selecting-a-subfolder-to-upload-based-on-the-response) has been successfully resolved. Therefore, I am looking for a solution to the following problem. The respondent is to submit the file using the form. How to send him a link to this file (with download permissions but not editing) or send the file itself (e.g. by e-mail).
Folders are created based on the responses from the form, so at the stage of creating the form, I do not know the names and IDs of these folders.

Comment: Hi there! I understand that you have a Form where users can upload a file, and you want that file to be either emailed to the user after submitting or sharing the Drive file with the user. Is my understanding correct? Feel free to show some examples if it isn't. So where do you find difficulties? Which step is slowing you down? Share the script if you need help with it.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. 
Unfortunately, I do not have the sample code, because I am completely new in this topic. I diagnosed the problem based on the review. I have found solutions for emailing a file that is already on Google Disk or for sending a link to such a file. In each of these solutions, the file was already on the Google Disk.
If you can help me by giving any tips, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you already have developed scripts for *«emailing a file that is already on Google* Drive *or for sending a link to such a file»*, and your goal is to run such scripts when a file is uploaded to a Form. If my understanding of your scenario is correct, then you are very close to reaching your goals.

First of all let me clarify that the files uploaded on Form populate a Drive folder automatically. You can see in your main Drive folder (`My Drive`) that there is one folder for your form, and inside that folder there is one additional folder for every question in your form that requires a file upload. Please keep in mind that all respondent users will share the same folders.

Knowing the fundamentals discussed above, you only need one additional function to connect the new files in your Drive folder to your already existing scripts for mailing the files. To do so you can set up a [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that fires your scripts. To connect your scripts with the forms responses folder, you should copy the folder ID into your function. Let me know if you need further clarifications with this approach.